# Lagrange Multipliers for Olympiad Question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The question is as follows:

Given $a,b,c,d > 0$ and integers, and that $a+b+c+d=40$ -- find the maximum value of $ab+bc+cd$

There is a way to answer this question without using calculus (I am aware of this) but I was wondering how I could apply the method of legrange multipliers? (I have only just learnt the concept)

My attempt gave me a maximum that was 1 off!

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange multipliers are not very adequate here. Note that $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

First, we have
$$(a+c)(b+d)=ab+ad+bc+cd$$

Then
$$ab+bc+cd=(a+c)(b+d)-ad$$
So we should try maximize $(a+c)(b+d)$ and minimize $ad$.

To maximize $(a+c)(b+d)$, note that $(a+c)+(b+d)=40$, so we have to maximize the product of two numbers, given their sum. It is well known that this happens when the numbers (namely, $a+c$ and $b+d$) are equal, so we can say that $a+c=b+d=20$.

Now, to minimize $ad$, simply take the least possible values for $a$ and $d$. Since they are positive integers, we have $a=d=1$. Then the solution comes with the values
$$a=1,b=19,c=19,d=1$$

Comment: I'm aware of how to obtain the solution by other means -- I am curious as to why I can't use calculus

Comment: @HughEntwistle Try using Lagrange multiplier for $a, b, c, d\geq 1$.

Comment: @JackyChong I'm afraid I don't know how, I have only just learnt about them

Comment: I assume it is not possible to do so? But it's strange that we can't add a constraint that the integers must be positive

Comment: Calculus is not adequate. If you remove the condition that $a,b,c,d$ are integers, there is no solution. Take $a=d=\epsilon>0$ and $b=c=20-\epsilon$. Informally, when $\epsilon$ becomes smaller, the sum $ab+bc+cd$ becomes bigger, so it has no maximum (it is bounded above by $400$, though).

Comment: Hmm okay, I guess this intuition also explains why we cannot find a minimum either -- but there a minimum does exist when the constrain is that $a,b,c,d$ must be positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You take the partial derivatives of $f-\lambda g$ with respect to all variables, including $\lambda$, and set them equal to zero, where $f$ is the function to be maximized and $g$ is the constraint. The intuition is that this guarantees that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel, so the function and the constraint are tangent, which must occur at any constrained extremum.

In this case we have $(ab + bc+ cd)-\lambda(a+b+c+d-40)$. Set the partial derivatives equal to zero and we have the equations $b-\lambda=0$, $a+c-\lambda=0$, $b+d-\lambda=0$, $c-\lambda=0$, and the constraint $a+b+c+d=40$.

The solution is $a=d=0$, and $b=c=20.$  the value of the function is 400.

I guess since you require the numbers to be positive, this solution is outside your domain. However this is the only solution you can get by Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: The numbers $a,b,c,d$ must be positive.

Comment: And integers too. For that solution, this method doesn't apply. If you want to do Lagrange multipliers, though, this is how

Comment: So there is no way of giving another constraint that $a,b,c,d > 0$ ?

Comment: I got the same solution -- but the actual solution is 399

Comment: @HughEntwistle no, not to my knowledge with the Lagrange multipliers method